# How to get value from recyclerview and sum it to get grand total of value in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So i tried to get the price value from Firebase RecycleView and sum it to get the sum of it. but i can't figure it how it's work

here's my adapter

```
public class StatusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StatusAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Status> listStatus;
    private Context context;
    String uid;



    public interface dataListener{
        void onDeleteData(Status data, int position);
    }

    dataListener listener;

    public StatusAdapter(ArrayList<Status> listStatus, Context context) {
        this.listStatus = listStatus;
        this.context = context;
        listener = (ProsesPesananActivity)context;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView shopId, ukuran, total,status,image,cartTotal;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private LinearLayout ListItem;
        long sum;


        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //Menginisialisasi View-View yang terpasang pada layout RecyclerView kita
            shopId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemKey);
            ukuran = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemUkuran);
            total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTotal);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemStatus);
            ListItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecStatusImage);





        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Membuat View untuk Menyiapkan dan Memasang Layout yang Akan digunakan pada RecyclerView
        View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_status, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(V);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        //Mengambil Nilai/Value yenag terdapat pada RecyclerView berdasarkan Posisi Tertentu
        final String shopId = listStatus.get(position).getShopId();
        final String ukuran = listStatus.get(position).getUkuran();
        final String status = String.valueOf(listStatus.get(position).getStatus());
        final String total = String.valueOf(listStatus.get(position).getTotal());
        final String image = listStatus.get(position).getUrl();




        //Memasukan Nilai/Value kedalam View (TextView: shopId, ukuran, total)

        holder.shopId.setText("shopId: "+shopId);
        holder.ukuran.setText("ukuran: "+ukuran);
        holder.total.setText("total: "+total);
        holder.status.setText("status"+status);


    }

    private int grandTotal(ArrayList<Status> items){

        int totalPrice = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += items.get(i).getTotal();
        }

        return totalPrice;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //Menghitung Ukuran/Jumlah Data Yang Akan Ditampilkan Pada RecyclerView
        return listStatus.size();
    }

}
```

as you can see i tried to sum it with totalPrice method but when i call this method in mainActivity it doesn't work because it need to be static method and i cant get any array if i use static method. so is there any way to make it happen ?

Comment: Create a method that can be called with an instance and call it via instance right after you call notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: can you show me how to implement it ? im new in here. sorry

Comment: Generally, you can not call the other class mathod directly. But, I have a suggestion for this is to make an interface which return int value in which you will pass the grandTotal value when you will get the total completely. And so, implement your interface method at mainActivity.java file. For more help let me know.

Comment: sir you can send data in main activity through listener, which is you already use in recyclerview adapter for deleteData() . same as it is you can make one more function in it to pass the total of items, and implement that interface in main activity to get the call back .

Answer (score 0):

You can not use it in Adapter, because each time you scrol the recyclerview grand sum changes.
you shoud do it in AsyncTask where you load data to Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `grandTotal` function in `StatusAdapter` because you are defining it as `private` modifier.

What you should do, is simply change `grandTotal` function to `public` modifier like this

```
    public int grandTotal(ArrayList<Status> items){

        int totalPrice = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += items.get(i).getTotal();
        }

        return totalPrice;
    }
```

Then in your `MainActivity`, you can simply call this method like this

```
int grandTotalPrice = statusAdapter.grandTotal(statusArray);
```